# How to create a POST method that receives a list of strings in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postman

I am using Postman to do some tests before implementing it in my android application.
I created a WebAPI in ASP.NET MVC and created a method to add the locations to database. For that I get a list of strings, but an error always appears saying that the method does not exist. What am I doing wrong?

My Code:

```
  public class LocalNotificacaoController : ApiController
    {
        private TransEntities db = new TransEntities();

    // POST: api/LocalNotificacao
        public bool PostNotificacao(List<string> locais, string emailUser, string tipo_login, string hash)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return false;
            }
    
            //will go through each location
    
            foreach (string local in locais)
            {
    
                //will check if the location already exists
    
                var PlaceExists = db.Find_Local_Notificacao(local).ToList();
    
    
                //if the location does not exist, it will add the location to the Notification table

                if (PlaceExists.Count == 0)
                {
                    //add place
                    db.Add_Local_Notificacao(local);
                }
    
                //get location id
                var res = db.Get_IDLocal_Notificacao(local);
                int id = 0;
                foreach (var item in res)
                {
                    id = item.Value;
                }
    
                //add location and user to the Notification-User table
                db.Add_Notificacao_Utilizador(id, emailUser, tipo_login);
                db.SaveChanges();
    
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**POSTMAN**

[image]

Comment: Not sure that multiple `locais` in query string will work correctly. After marking method as `HttpPost` (also you can try naming your method just `Post`)  possibly you will need to change query string to something like `locais[0]=str&locais[1]=str1.....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems with what you're trying to call in Postman, but the first thing you need to do is add an `HttpPost` attribute to `PostNotificacao`. Without this, it will process `GET` requests instead, so trying to `POST` to it wouldn't work:

```
// POST: api/LocalNotificacao
[HttpPost]
public bool PostNotificacao([FromUri] List<string> locais, string emailUser, string tipo_login, string hash)
```

The default route configuration can be found in your `App_Start\WebApiConfig` class. It should look like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Unless you have changed that default route to prefix everything with `WebApi`, you don't need to add `WebApi` in Postman when trying to call a controller. With all of that, the URL you should be using in Postman to call it will be something like:

```
https://localhost:44351/api/LocalNotificacao?locais[0]=test1&locais[1]=test2&emailUser=hi@me.com&tipo_login=cool&hash=blah
```

where:

1. `localhost:44351` is your base address
2. `/api/LocalNotificacao` is because you're calling an API controller called `LocalNotificacaoController`, which by default are configured to run under `/api`
3. `locais[0]=test1&locais[1]=test2` is what you need to do in order to bind multiple values to your `List<string> locais` collection

Also, just so you're aware, this:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return false;
}
```

is going to do nothing in your code, because you are only using primitive types as parameters to your method (e.g. `string`). Have a read of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) to understand how to use that.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I'm still a beginner, so I had some problems, but I did understand. I use WebApi in the url pk I'm accessing the method by IP. And putting url locais=test&locais = test1 worked the same way.
The method is that  was implemented in the wrong way. And thanks for the explanation of ModelState.IsValid).